# CLRS - Random search - How to calculate Expected number of picks?

Tags: algorithm, probability

It is CLRS question. The question is from third edition of CLRS book: 5-2-b.

The random search is an algorithm where you have to pick an element randomly and compare it with the searched element. If equals, we need to stop. Now, suppose you have exactly one element with index i such that A[i]=x (x is searched element in the array). 
What is the expected number of indices into A that we must pick before we find x?
Also, how can we find the expected number of indices when we have more than 1 indices values which are equal to x?

Answer (score 1):

We can define a random variable X = Number of iterations until selecting the target element.  If you generalize the terminology so that 'iterations' is termed 'trials' and 'selecting the target element' is termed 'success', then you have X = Number of trials until success.

This random variable has a well known distribution.  It is a [geometric distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution) given a probability of success parameter, p.  The expected value of a geometric distribution is E(X) = 1/p.

To apply the geometric distribution to the problem, the probability of success, p, must be determined.  For the case where only one index contains the target value, p = 1/n where n is the size of the searched collection.  So in this case, E(X) = n.

For the general case where any number of indices map to the target value, p = m / n where m is the the number of indices that map to the target value.  So in this case E(X) = n / m.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there are k failures before we find element x. So Pr{k failures}=k/(n-1). now E(X)=sum of Pr{k failures} for k=1 to n. therefore, E(X)=n(n+1)/2(n-1).

Comment: This answer is not correct. Correct answer is:                    E(X) = ∑i=1∞ ((n-1)/n)i-1 . (1/n) . i
       = (1/(n-1)) ∑i=1∞ i . ((n-1)/n)i
now assuming (n-1)/n as x and applying taylor's theorem,
E(X) = 1/(n-1) . (n-1)/n / (1 - (n-1)/n)2
       = n

Comment: Sorry, i thought latex will work here.. Clear answer [link](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/39/equation.gif)